# Test Double tap event

Tags: android, junit

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate the doulbe tap event. I tried

```
TouchUtils.clickView(...)
```

two times in a row but it did not work. I tried also in this way:

```
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    eventTime +=200;
    downTime +=200;

    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, mainview.getWidth()/2, mainview.getHeight()/2, 0);
    instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);

    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, mainview.getWidth()/2, mainview.getHeight()/2, 0);
    instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);

    downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    eventTime +=200;
    downTime += 200;

    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, mainview.getWidth()/2, mainview.getHeight()/2, 0);
    instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);

    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, mainview.getWidth()/2, mainview.getHeight()/2, 0);
    instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);
```

but the event still does not trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the tests covering the onDoubleTap gesture detector](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-cts/android/view/cts/GestureDetectorTestUtil.java.htm) you need to use `TouchUtils.tapView`